# Is there a reStructuredText markup editor for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, restructuredtext

Is there a WiKiText editor plugin for reStructuredText under eclipse? When I edit a .textile file, I get various intelligent editing features (such as line folding) and a preview panel. I find that there are references to reStructuredText under various MyLyn packages, but after installing them I still can't find a reStructuredText editor. Is that because there isn't one?

Thanks. Kent

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably this answer is too late, but yet it is worth to add it for future readers :)

There is an "official" list of editors here:
http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/links.html

One of the tools mentioned is the Eclipse plugin indeed:
http://resteditor.sourceforge.net/. I've been using it for few days only (I'm also researching in this direction now :) ), but so far so good.

P.S. I haven't been able to install the "color theme mapper" for that plugin - so should you have troubles installing that plugin - uncheck the "color theme mapper" when installing it from update site.

Comment: Color theme mapper requires that you install https://github.com/fhd/eclipse-color-theme first.

Comment: Ha! Indeed, that's quite logical :) Didn't know about it though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is the [ReST Editor plugin](http://resteditor.sourceforge.net/) for eclipse.

It works really well and he provide an integration with Eclipse Color Theme (Use the update site to install the Eclipse Color Theme integration).

Comment: Note this requires Eclipse 3.6

Answer (score 0):

There is no ReST plugin, but you can make one yourself, as example using [Colorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/).

Colorer has an [API](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/hrc-ref/index.html) for new language descriptions, and there's a [plugin](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html) for Eclipse.

There's even an [example](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/other/Color5Eclipse_Newlanguagedoc.html) on how to add new languages to Eclipse this way. It is very easy :-)

If you don't know the ReST syntax specifications, you can take these as a reference:

- [Plugin for GEdit](http://textmethod.com/browser/rst_gedit_tools/rst.lang)
- [Plugin for VIM](http://www.georgevreilly.com/blog/CategoryView,category,reStructuredText.aspx)

You just need to translate these to the Colorer syntax and you'll have ReST highlighting in Eclipse.

Comment: If anyone does this, plz post a new answer. :)